# How can I get an HTML page as a string via PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I am fetching some info via PHP from a webpage using `simple_php_dom` and curl. The problem is that the page is not built correctly so the DOM object contains erroneous info.

How can I get the HTML file as a string in a PHP var so that I can run a regular expression through it?

Curl doesn't work as it is ignoring the bad part.
`simple_html_dom.php` has the same issue.
`wget` doesn't work since I don't have permissions for it on the server.

Answer (score 13):

[file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) — Reads entire file into a string

```
string file_get_contents ( 
    string $filename [, int $flags= 0 [, resource $context [, int $offset= -1 [, int $maxlen= -1 ]]]] 
)
```

from the manual:

> This function is similar to file(), except that file_get_contents() returns the file in a string, starting at the specified offset up to maxlen bytes. On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.
>
> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

And it works both with webpages and files. You can grab the HTML, just by using "http://whatever.com/page.html" as $filename.

Comment: Only works if allow_url_fopen is enabled, though. There's really no reason that this should work with curl as well.

Comment: It also ignores part of the file :S

The only one so far that really gets the file correctly is wget, which i can't use :S

Comment: You can test it with this:
http://www.zonlusomundo.pt/txt_geral.php?Gid=1579830&zona=filme compare the size of wget and the size with that

Comment: Maybe the site has some kind of user-agent policy. How does wget identify itself to the site? If you pull google.com, it (usualy) loads perfectly with both file_get_contents and wget. Maybe you need to set a user-agent string for file_get_contents()

Answer (score 4):

With curl you would want to make sure that you're setting the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER parameter to ensure that the page is retrieved as a string, e.g.:

```
    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0):

I used cURL to get the file into a string (simple_html_dom::load_file just wraps file_get_contents) then using simple_html_dom load (from string) method to parse it.  That works for some URL's but it is failing in this case when the URL has a parameter string.  It is fetching the URL as if it had not a parameter string.  I set an agent with curl to impersonate a browser but no dice.

Sorry this is not an answer really, but maybe using curl will work for some people for whom the fopen setting is a problem.